# getting current project path from IJavaEditorTextHover

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, hover

i am developing an eclipse plugin and i need the path to the project of the user. I wnat to obtain it on my class which implements `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.hover.IJavaEditorTextHover`

I have tried doing:

```
IEditorPart editorPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor(); 

String activeProjectName = "";
if (editorPart != null) 
{ 
    IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput)editorPart.getEditorInput() ; 
    IFile file = input.getFile(); 
    IProject activeProject = file.getProject(); 
    activeProjectName = activeProject .getName(); 
} 
IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(activeProjectName);
```

But when i do that on my my class which implements org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.hover.IJavaEditorTextHover, i keep getting nullpointerExcetion on

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
```

I have tried this method before, but on a class that extends AbstractHandler and it worked. Why can´t i get IProject from IJavaEditorTextHover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IJavaEditorTextHover` has a `setEditor(IEditorPart editor)` method so you can use that rather than trying to find the active editor.

Your current code may be looking for an active workbench or page or editor before there actually is one.

Comment: but who can call setEditor? IJavaEditorTextHover will execute the method getHoverInfo() each time my mouse is over a java method on the editor and i want my IJavaTextEditorHover to have the IProject before the method ends.

Comment: The Java editor calls `setEditor` when it creates the text hover from the extension point. See `JavaEditorTextHoverDescriptor` and `JavaEditorTextHoverProxy`.